# Facebook JavaScript SDK unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

Here's m code :

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId  : '270423476xxxxx',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
</script>

<fb:registration 
fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
redirect-uri="http://booktrolley.in/beta"
width="530">
```

Now if you go to my page on : http://www.booktrolley.in/beta/fbreg.php

There's this "Loading" animation that continues to be there, even after the page loads.Why is that so ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your app registered with `booktrolley.in` or `pedurology.org`? in your frame page try adding a full html page structure with `<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">` tag ..etc

Comment: @ifaour its registered with booktrolley.in .I'v edited the page a bit . Hitting register doesn't seem to have any effect now :|

Thanks for the help

Comment: So your Site URL in your App settings is poiting to `booktrolley.in` but you are initializing the JS-SDK on a different domain, right? Also the code in `pedurology.org` is not correct, something like [this](http://pastebin.com/ZSVWpfB3) is better.

Comment: @ifaour I can't thank you enough ! Please submit the above comment as an answer,and i will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the plugin in a frame but your page's HTML structure is not correct, here's a better approach:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root" > </div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var wid=$(document).width()-20;
    $("#fb").attr('width',wid);

    });
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
<fb:registration redirect-uri="http://booktrolley.in/" 
 fields='[
   {"name":"name"},
   {"name":"foo","description":"Type foo","type":"text"},
   {"name":"bar","description":"Type bar","type":"text"},
   {"name":"facebooker","description":"Pick Paul","type":"select","options":
     {"coder":"Paul","pm":"Austin","partners":"Cat"}},
   {"name":"check","description":"Check this","type":"checkbox"},
   {"name":"date","description":"Dec 16 2010","type":"date"},
   {"name":"city","description":"Calgary","type":"typeahead","categories":
     ["city"]}]' 
 onvalidate="validate"></fb:registration> 

<script> 
function validate(form) {
  errors = {};
  if (form.foo !== "foo") {
    errors.foo = "You didn't type foo";
  }
  if (form.bar !== "bar") {
    errors.bar = "You didn't type bar";
  }
  if (form.facebooker !== "coder") {
    errors.facebooker = "Pick the geeky one";
  }
  if (!form.check) {
    errors.check = "Check the little box";
  }
  if (form.date !== '12/16/2010') {
    errors.date = "That isn't the launch date";
  }
  if (form.city.id !== '111983945494775') {
    errors.city = "That isn't Calgary, Alberta";
  }
  return errors;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the ancient Egyptians called "a bug"

Comment: But is there seriously no way to get around this flaw ?